# How to change the date format from dd-MM-yyyy to yyyy-mm-dd ,i have got results as Thu Jan 02 00:00:00 IST 2014

Tags: java, mysql, servlets

```
 HttpSession session = req.getSession(false);
 if(session!=null)
 {    
     SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
     SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
     DateFormat sdf2 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd");

     String studid = req.getParameter("studid");
     int studentid = Integer.parseInt(studid);
     String firstName = req.getParameter("firstname");
     String lastName = req.getParameter("lastname");
     String emailstudent = req.getParameter("emailstud");
     String qualification = req.getParameter("qualification");
     String dateintervieww = req.getParameter("dtintervieww");
     try {

         java.util.Date dtt_intervw = sdf.parse(dateintervieww);
         String dateintervw = sdf1.format(dtt_intervw);
         dtt_intervw = sdf1.parse(dateintervw);
         dateintervw  = sdf2.format(dtt_intervw);

         dtt_intervw = sdf2.parse(dateintervw);
         dateintervw  = sdf2.format(dtt_intervw);


     } catch (ParseException e1) {
         // TODO Auto-generated catch block
         e1.printStackTrace();
     }

     String joining_course = req.getParameter("joiningcourse");
     String ending_course = req.getParameter("endingcourse");
     String medicalinsurdate4rm = req.getParameter("mediinsurancedat4rm");
     String medicalinsurdatto = req.getParameter("mediinsurancedatto");

     String drive_location = req.getParameter("drivelocation");
     String course_offered = req.getParameter("courseoffered");

     String place_training = req.getParameter("placetraining");
     String modeselection = req.getParameter("modeselection");
     String selectprocedure = req.getParameter("selectprocedure");
     String bankacccnt_no = req.getParameter("bankaccntno");
     String Travel_exp  = req.getParameter("travelexpense");
     double trvl_exp = Double.parseDouble(Travel_exp);
     String medicalinsurnum = req.getParameter("mediinsurno");
     String Transferto = req.getParameter("transferto");

     String leaving_hostel = req.getParameter("leavinghostel");
     String placementstatus = req.getParameter("placementstatus");

     String appoint_letter = req.getParameter("appoint_letter");
     String select_month1 = req.getParameter("selectmonth1");
     String year1 = req.getParameter("year1");

     String select_month2 = req.getParameter("selectmonth2");
     String year2 = req.getParameter("year2");

     String select_month3 = req.getParameter("selectmonth3");
     String year3 = req.getParameter("year2");

     String book_return = req.getParameter("book_returns");

     LoginBean lgbean = new LoginBean();
     lgbean.setStudid(studentid);
     lgbean.setFirstname(firstName);
     lgbean.setLastname(lastName);
     lgbean.setEmail(emailstudent);
     lgbean.setQualification(qualification);
     lgbean.setDateinterview(dateintervieww);
     lgbean.setJoiningcourse(joining_course);
     lgbean.setEndingcourse(ending_course);
     lgbean.setMediinsurancedat4rm(medicalinsurdate4rm);
     lgbean.setMediinsurancedatto(medicalinsurdatto);

     lgbean.setDrivelocation(drive_location);
     lgbean.setCourseoffered(course_offered);
     lgbean.setPlacetraining(place_training);
     lgbean.setModeselection(modeselection);
     lgbean.setSelectprocedure(selectprocedure);
     lgbean.setBankaccntno(bankacccnt_no);
     lgbean.setTravelexpense(trvl_exp);
     lgbean.setMedicalinsuranceno(medicalinsurnum);
     lgbean.setTransferto(Transferto);

     lgbean.setLeavinghostel(leaving_hostel);
     lgbean.setPlacementstatus(placementstatus);
     lgbean.setAppoint_letter(appoint_letter);
     lgbean.setSelectmonth1(select_month1);
     lgbean.setYear1(year1);

     lgbean.setSelectmonth2(select_month2);
     lgbean.setYear2(year2);

     lgbean.setSelectmonth3(select_month3);
     lgbean.setYear3(year3);

     lgbean.setBook_returns(book_return);

     serviceclass sc = new serviceclass();  
     int l =  sc.submitstudentrecord(lgbean);

     if(l>0)
     {
         resp.sendRedirect("studentrecordpagee.do");
     }
     else
     {
         resp.sendRedirect("studgenrartereport.do");
     }

 }
 else
 {
     resp.sendRedirect("logOut.do");
 }
```

Comment: You've posted an enormous, badly-formatted block of code, with no obvious attempt to reduce the scope of this to *only* showing the problem, and no clear description *of* the problem. Please read http://tinyurl.com/stack-hints

Comment: `mm` stands for minute, and `MM` for month! Have you noticed the difference?

Comment: What do you mean by "I have got results as ... " - what part of your program is giving you those?  And what do `firstname`, `lastname`, `emailstudent` and all the numerous other fields that you've mentioned have to do with your question?  Isn't this a question about date formats?  Perhaps you could try to post just enough code to demonstrate your question.  It's also really not clear whether your problem is that you're getting an unexpected format, or an unexpected date, or both.  Please show exactly what you are expecting, at which point of your program, and what you're getting instead.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
try {
        SimpleDateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
        String date = "01-11-2014";
        Date d = inputFormat.parse(date);
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

        System.out.println(formatter.format(d));
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```